# Question on deleting one message in thread Gmail

Tags: gmail

I wanted to delete only one message from a conversation in Gmail. So,  I've opened the conversation that contains the message I want to delete. selected  the more arrow next to the Reply button in the message's title bar, and selected Delete this message from the menu that comes up.

Now my question is, this message deleted only from me , not from  the entire people in the conversation (to, cc, or bcc), right?

Comment: Email is closely modeled after sending letters or postcards per mail. Whatever you do with your copy doesn't affect anyone elses copy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes. This message is deleted ONLY from you.**

Why this happens?
When someone sends an email, one can decide to send it to one person or more than one.
When it is just one person, the sender places the recipient's name in the `to` field

When there are more than 1 person, one can also use the `cc` and `bcc` fields.

`cc`= **carbon copy**
`bcc`= **blind carbon copy**

As you understand, those emails are already in the other recipients' mailboxes and canNOT be affected by any action of yours.

So once again. You can do whatever you want with the messages in your inbox. It makes no difference to others